# The aggregate function GROUP BY and SUM return inconsisten data?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have this query that looks like okay(to me :)), but returns inconsistent data. The sum of some project return the correct data but some are not. Please help me spot the problem please.

```
SELECT 
TRIM(`alias`),
TRIM(project), 
SUM(`hours`)
FROM `dtr`
WHERE TRIM(`alias`) IN     ('benjie','JM','myleen','alain_a','catzpantoja','jed','jeanie','mai','cherryfe','zeek','Jay-R','daisy','jeanie_tc') 
AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-09-21' AND '2013-10-20'
GROUP BY TRIM(`project`)
ORDER BY TRIM(`alias`), TRIM(`project`);
```

Comment: How could we spot anything without actual data posted?

Comment: That's because your usage of `group by` is invalid (standard) SQL but MySQL chooses to return inconsistent data rather than rejecting it. See here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should group by all other selected items that not appear in the aggregate function, i.e. sum()